# Need help about the meaning of V+ するからいけないのよ (V+suru kara ikenai no yo)

Tags: grammar, meaning, japanese-to-english

When reading , I met with this grammar , and not sure about its meaning. Much thanks if anyone can help me understand correctly o/

Example:
**変に意識するからいけないのよ**

I have 2 guesses :

1/You shouldn't have weird/strange thoughts about it.

and

2/Do not have weird/strange thoughts about it !

Answer (score 3):

The first translation sounds perfect for me. It must be an advice or criticism thrown toward someone who looks suspicious.

Translating the seconds one back, it becomes like 変なこと考えないで！, which could never be an intention of the example you provide.

Answer (score 3):

There is not much grammar here.

いけない simply means “it’s not good”, “things don’t go well”, etc., and the part before から tells the reason the speaker thinks so. It’s not a grammaticalized expression like `[V ない-stem]-なくてはいけない`.

の is the explanatory particle and よ is a sentence-ending particle. This combination of のよ is normally used by women. A man would have probably said 変に意識するからいけないんだよ.

変に doesn’t necessarily mean “strangely”. It could simply mean “excessively”.